# Join many to many and merge the many refs into single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I've consulted similar questions but the question is different since I've a join with not just many to many but one to many as well.

user

```
+----+-------+---------------+
| id | first | department_id |
+----+-------+---------------+
|  1 | John  | 1             |
|  2 | Jane  | 2             |
+----+-------+---------------+
```

department

```
+----+------------+
| id |   name     |
+----+------------+
|  1 | purchasing |
|  2 | HR         |
|  3 | marketing  |
+----+------------+
```

role

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
|  2 | accounts |
|  3 | sales    |
+----+----------+
```

user_role

```
+--------+----------+
| user_id | role_id |
+--------+----------+
|      1  |       1 |
|      1  |       2 |
|      1  |       3 |
|      2  |       2 |
|      2  |       3 |
+--------+----------+
```

sql

```
SELECT user.first, GROUP_CONCAT(role.name), department.id AS 'department.id', department.name AS 'department.name'
FROM user 
INNER JOIN department ON user.department_id
INNER JOIN user_role ON user.id = user_role.user_id
INNER JOIN role ON user_role.role_id = role.id
GROUP BY user.name;
```

Expectation

```
John, "admin,accounts,sales", 1, purchasing
Jane, "accounts,sales", 2, HR
```

Essentially it's a 4 table join, with many to many and 1 to many with group concat function.

the query gives an error.

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'department.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: What's your query giving as the output ?

Comment: I've the error, see my edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the department is unique for each user you can use `max()` to get the department details to overcome the limitations posed by `group by`.

```
SELECT 
  user.first, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(role.name) AS roles, 
  max(department.id) AS department_id, 
  max(department.name) AS department_name
FROM user 
INNER JOIN department ON user.department_id = department.id
INNER JOIN user_role ON user.id = user_role.user_id
INNER JOIN role ON user_role.role_id = role.id
GROUP BY user.first;
```

Also if the user's name is not unique, you should:

```
GROUP BY user.id, user.first
```

Also the aliases of columns must not be enclosed in single quotes. Use backticks instead.

Comment: I see, got it. you used max because mysql restricts every column to be an aggregate function, right?

Comment: Yes, every column in the select list must be either in the group by clause or aggregated.

Comment: ok, and this restriction was imposed by the use of `GROUP_CONCAT` function or because of `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Because of group by. GROUP_CONCAT() is an aggregated column. As an alternative to max() you can use any_value().

Comment: I just did test without using `max` or `any_value` and it works, don't know. any idea

Comment: MySql allowes this when the attribute only_full_group_by is set to false, but the error you mention in the question means that it is set to true.

Comment: What MySql does is pick a value for the column (any value), but in your case there is only 1 value, so the result is correct. In another rdbms like sqlserver this would not be allowed.

Comment: You can find more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: i think because I didn't have `user.id` in my `select` and `group by` that's why it was throwing error.

Comment: ok, I'll use `any_value` to be safe, hopefully `any_value` is supported in mysql server too, otherwise I'll use max because I'll have a use case it to be cross platform db solution

Comment: Since `user.id` was not included in the group by neither in select, there is no problem. But just to be safe, use `user.id` in group by, if the names of the users are not unique. Also the error maybe was thrown because you surrounded the alias 'department.id' with single quotes instead of  backticks or square brackets.

Comment: ok, fixed, now using backticks, however square bracket you mean `[department.id]` ? it threw an error for me

Comment: Right, for mysql you must use backticks. The square brackets work in sql server and sqlite.

Comment: well i think i've to manage two sql scripts, because of backticks/quotes vs square brackets, single quote worked in mysql here, if it works in sql server then I've a cross platform script, otherwise :( I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: If you plan to migrate the code to sql server then you **must** use max() (there is no any_value() there).

Comment: sure, i've max in place now